# sprintf decimal separator

Tags: visual-c++

I need function sprintf to use default windows decimal separator. Following code always prints 12.5 in output:

```
double d=12.5;
char buffer [50];
sprintf (buffer, "%0.2f",d);
printf("%s", buffer);
```

What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: So long as your locale is set correctly then this should behave as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How to set locale then?

Answer (score 0):

So long as your locale is set correctly then this should behave as expected. To set your locale use [setlocale()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setlocale).